# How can I ensure value is in the custom class property at the NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create the custom class name with FileModel.

FileModel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FileModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *fileName;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *fileType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate   *editDate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger fileSize;

@end
```

I want to compare the particular string with the fileName.

I create the sample like below .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *fileSampleName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apple.png",@"banana.png",@"cherry.png",@"durian.png",@"grape.png",@"avocado.png", nil];

    NSMutableArray *fileData = [NSMutableArray new];
    FileModel *fileModel = nil;
    for( NSInteger i = 0 ; i < fileSampleName.count  ; i++){
        fileModel = [FileModel new];
        fileModel.fileName = [fileSampleName objectAtIndex:i];
        fileModel.fileType = @"photo";
        fileModel.fileSize = 0;
        fileModel.editDate = [NSDate new];
        [fileData addObject:fileModel];
    }

    // fileData's fileName containsObject @"grape" or not?
 }
```

NSArray has containsObject method.

But How can I check the @"grape" is containsObject using fileData at the custom class property filename?

I known using for loop compare one by one.

Did they have other method to check like containsObject?

--- edit---

I try to using indexOfObjectPassingTest method , But the result always is 1.

```
 BOOL result = [fileData indexOfObjectPassingTest:^ BOOL (id tr,NSUInteger index, BOOL *te){
 FileModel *fileModel = (FileModel*)tr;
 if([@"orange" isEqualToString: fileModel.fileName]){
      *te = YES; 
      return YES;
  }else{
      return NO;
  }}];
                                                                NSLog(@"result:%@",@(result)); // it always return 1
```

Why? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look that `NSArray` class reference in Xcode. One method you could use is `indexOfObjectPassingTest`. There are number of related methods depending on your needs. All take a block that's used to test objects to see if they meet whatever criteria you want. In your case you'd test the `fileName` string.

So you'd pass in a closure that compared the `fileName` property of each object to your desired filename.